# WebSphere migration appears in eclipse always

Tags: eclipse, git, websphere

I use `WebSphere Application Server 8.5` with `Eclipse Mars 4.5.2`. My problem is when I open `Eclipse` a migration for my server runtime appears always.

[image: undefined server runtime]

Both entries are the same?

I also have the whole project in `git` so I could check what has changed after migration. The interesting thing is that only  the date, which is the first line from the `com.ibm.ws.ast.st.migration.prefs` file, has changed.

Has someone a hint how I could stop this "unnecessary" cycling migration.

Comment: What is the "cycle" here?  If it happened once, then the question might be "what do I select", but it sounds like you're saying you make some choice, save it, but then what (when you reopen Eclipse it loses your change)?  Or are you moving to a new Eclipse or doing a rebuild?    What is the "always" here?

Comment: I select it and apply it. And then I reopen eclipse and I get migration dialog again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving the problem we changed two settings:

1) in the `.classpath` we replaced the following `classpathentry`:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/WebSphere Application Server v8.5 JRE">
    <attributes>
       <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

with:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
```

2) in the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file we removed the following line:

```
<runtime name="WebSphere Application Server v8.5"/>
```